# Probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $X\ge0$ a non negative random variable in (Ω,F,P) and  $\int_Ω XdP=m<\infty$.

Prove that  $$ν(Α)=\dfrac{1}{m}\int_A XdP, with A\in F$$ is **probability measure** in (Ω,F,P).

Do I have to prove the monotonicity and continuity in order to be a probability measure?

or i have to prove $ν(\{\varnothing\})=0$ and $\sumν( A_i) = ν(\bigcup{  } A_i).$

Any help, tips would saved my day.

Comment: You have to show $\nu$ is a nonnegative, countably additive function on $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\nu(\Omega)=1$.

Comment: Did you mean a probability measure, rather than a "measure probability"?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker so, if I we claim that since X is a non-negative variable then the integral is also non-negative and by replacing A with Ω v(Ω)=1, is that all we need?

Comment: @johanpaul You still have to prove $\sigma$-additivity. You can do that either using the monone convergence theorem or the dominated convergence theorem here.

Comment: @MichaelGreineckerIf I may, is it possible to show us here the proof of this property  using the convergence theorem? I would appreciate it a lot.